# What are .composermodule-files and what do they do in the Snapchat APK?

Tags: android, apk, apktool, snapchat

I'm looking into the snapchat APK. I used `apktool` to decompile the APK-file and found a bunch of `.composermodule` files in the assets folder. I have tried googling but all results point towards the composer package manager for PHP (https://getcomposer.org/).

What are `.composermodule`-files in this context? And how do I decompile/use them?